# Read between 2 offsets of a file

Tags: python

I was wondering how the read() function can be used to read between 2 offsets that are in hex?

I tried using this to convert the offset values to int, but I get a syntax error for the read.() line. Any ideas?

```
OFFSETS = ('3AF7','3ECF')
OFFSETE = ('3B04','3EDE')

for r, d, f in os.walk("."):
    for hahahoho, value in enumerate(OFFSETS and OFFSETE):
        try:
           with open(os.path.join(r,f), 'rb' ) as fileread:
                 texttoprint = fileread.seek(int(OFFSETS[hahahoho], 16) -1)
                 yeeha = texttoprint.read[int(OFFSETS[hahahoho], 16) -1 : int(OFFSETE[damn],16)]
                 print (yeeha)
                 hahahoho + 1
```

this is not the entire code thou, just posted the ones i need help with =(

EDIT:
Alright, i think i should listen to the advice of you people this is the entire code

```
nost = 1
OFFSETS = ('3AF7','3ECF')
OFFSETE = ('3B04','3EDE')
endscript = 'No'
nooffile = 1

import os, glob, sys, tempfile

try:
    directory = input('Enter your directory:').replace('\\','\\\\')
    os.chdir(directory)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print ('Directory not found!')
    endscript = 'YES!'

if endscript == 'YES!':
    sys.exit('Error. Be careful of what you do to your computer!')
else:
    if os.path.isfile('Done.txt') == True:
        print ('The folder has already been modified!')
else:
    print ('Searching texts...\r\n')
    print ('Printing...')
    for r, d, f in os.walk("."):
        for HODF in f:
            if HODF.endswith(".hod") or "." not in HODF:
                for damn, value in enumerate(OFFSETS and OFFSETE):
                    try:
                        with open(os.path.join(r,HODF), 'rb' ) as fileread:
                            fileread.seek(int(OFFSETS[damn],16) -1)
                            yeeha = fileread.read(int(OFFSETE[damn], 16) - (int(OFFSETS[damn],16) -1))
                            if b'?\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00Leg2.' not in yeeha and b'?\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00Leg2_r.' not in yeeha:
                                print (yeeha)
                        damn + 1
                    except FileNotFoundError:
                        print('Invalid file path!')
                        os._exit(1)
                    except IndexError:
                        print ('File successfully modified!')
                nooffile = nooffile + 1
                nost = 1

    print ('\r\n'+str(nooffile)+' files read.',)        
    print ('\tANI_list.txt, End.dat, Group.txt, Head.txt, Tail.dat files ignored.')
    print ('\r\nFiles successfully read! Hope you found what you are looking for!')
```

May I know whats wrong with it? Cause it works just fine for me

Comment: `enumerate(OFFSETS and OFFSETE)` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: well it works for me, the problem here is that i don't know how the read() works

Comment: `OFFSETS and OFFSETE` is in your case exactly the same as `OFFSETE`, as `OFFSETS` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: hmm, thanks for the advice people, but seriously what i really need help is with the read line. how can i use variables in read() commands? such as f.read(variable : variable)? help please?

Answer (score 6):

There are other problems with your code, but it sounds like you want to solve that yourself. When it comes to reading a particular byte range from a file, you can do that like this:

```
start = 1000
end = 1020    # Just examples
fileread.seek(start)
stuff = fileread.read(end - start)
```

That is, you start by seeking to the start position, and then you read as many bytes as you need (that is 20, in this example).

**EDIT:**

The only real "problem" with your code is that you're using `enumerate` in a strange and weird fashion that makes it completely unnecessary. The expression `OFFSETS and OFFSETE` will simply evaluate to `OFFSETE`, making `OFFSETS and` completely superfluous in it. Then, you're only actually using the first value from `enumerate` (the index), which makes `enumerate` itself superfluous: You could just have used `range(len(OFFSETE))` instead.

More proper, however, would be to loop directly over the values instead of going via an index, like this:

```
for start, end in zip(OFFSETS, OFFSETE):
    # snip
    fileread.seek(int(start, 16) - 1)
    yeeha = fileread.read(int(start, 16) - int(end, 16) - 1)
```

The other things are more like slight uglinesses that could be eliminated to make your code much nicer, but aren't strictly speaking wrong. Among them are that you don't need to represent your offsets as strings, but could use hexadecimal literals instead; that you open the file multiple times for no reason, that the `hohohaha + 1` expression is completely superfluous, and that you could just bake the `- 1` extra offsets directly into your actual offsets instead of adding it later.

I would write it closer to this instead:

```
OFFSETS = [0x3AF7 - 1, 0x3ECF - 2]
OFFSETE = [0x3B04 - 1, 0x3EDE - 2]

for r, d, f in os.walk("."):
    for fn in f:
        with open(os.path.join(r, fn), "rb") as fp:
            for start, end in zip(OFFSETS, OFFSETE):
                fp.seek(start)
                yeeha = fp.read(start - end)
                # Do whatever it is you need with yeeha
```

Comment: Thanks! This is all I need. Well there might be a problem with my code, but so long as it does what i need it to, there is no point in fixing it. Why fix something that is not broken just because its problematic?

Comment: @Aesreal: let me guess, you're a mathematician or scientist.  :)  If you think programmers are going to let you get away with screwed-up code on a public website, you are in for a surprise!

Comment: *"so long as it does what i need it to, there is no point in fixing it"* -- There is a case to be made that it would productive to know what the various constructs you use actually do, however. It would help you avoid future trouble.

Comment: Alright, I've posted the code that I have, could you explain whats wrong for me please?

Comment: Thanks! Well I'm still new to coding so right now what I'm focusing on is to make sure that my codes don't go wrong, since this is something that I need urgently. Afterwards, when I have time, I'm gonna learn how to refine the codes that I make. Thank you for taking your time off to help me =D When I get enough reputation, I'll be sure to up your rep!